# Is it useful to design a pedal with kickstand?

Tags: design, kickstand

i am working on a project, trying to combine a pedal and kickstand.
It can provide temporary balance for the bike, and to take better bike photo easily.
Do you think you ever need such a product?

[image]

Image from the internet

Comment: Sorry, we don't do survey questions here, and especially not product research. But thank you for being clear about what you're doing.

Comment: Honestly I think it's a bad idea. Unless the kickstand is latched in a very secure (and therefore difficult to deploy) way, the chances of it dropping while pedalling, snagging the ground and causing a crash are likely to be unacceptably high. It may also weaken the crank if you're trying to save weight.

Comment: It's a thought.  But it would significantly increase the likelihood of damage to the pedal and crank if the bike is knocked over.

Comment: You take that many photos of your bike that you need a special stand for it ?

Comment: Bad idea. Whether you attach it permanently or make ad-hoc attachment. , it is error-prone.

Comment: This also would look more awkward than just leaning the bike up against something or carefully placing a pole-style kickstand if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not a great idea.

It's going to make the pedal heavier that it needs to be.

I would much rather have the weight of the stand on the frame instead of the pedal, because it adds rotating weight.

Comment: Rotating weight adds to the bike's acceleration time, but once you're rolling at top speed rotating weight is the same as weight elsewhere on the bike.     Also, what are you doing with your pedals that they accelerate and decelerate with every crank revolution ?

Comment: Accelerate and Decelerate as in rotate. Like: Push down, than pull back up ...

Comment: Your pedals turn at a constant rotational rate. That's different to accelerating and decelerating.

Comment: Alright, fixed it